# how to remove columns that has duplicate name in pandas but keep the one with maximum values in it?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have the below pandas dataframe and I need to keep only one date column that has maximum elements in it and eliminate rest:

```
date         value_1      date        value_2    date         value_3
01-01-1990   1            01-01-1990  2          01-01-1990   4
02-01-1990   3            02-01-1990  20         
                          03-01-1990  30
```

Output

```
date         value_1        value_2    value_3
01-01-1990   1              2          4
02-01-1990   3              20         
03-01-1990                  30
```

.T.drop_duplicates don't work. 
`df = df.loc[:,~df.columns.duplicated()]` keeps the first date column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
df1 = df.loc[:,df.columns.duplicated(keep=False)]
idx = np.argmax(df1.count().values)

df = df.loc[:,~df.columns.duplicated()].assign(date=df1.iloc[:, idx])
print (df)
         date  value_1  value_2  value_3
0  01-01-1990      1.0        2      4.0
1  02-01-1990      3.0       20      NaN
2  03-01-1990      NaN       30      NaN
```

**Details**:

First filter duplicated `date` columns:

```
df1 = df['date']
print (df1)
         date        date        date
0  01-01-1990  01-01-1990  01-01-1990
1  02-01-1990  02-01-1990         NaN
2         NaN  03-01-1990         NaN
```

Get number of non NaNs values by [`DataFrame.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.count.html):

```
print (df1.count())
date    2
date    3
date    1
dtype: int64
```

Columns names are same, so use [`np.argmax`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) for position:

```
print (df1.count().values)
[2 3 1]

idx = np.argmax(df1.count().values)
print (idx)
1
```

And last select by `iloc`:

```
print (df1.iloc[:, idx])
0    01-01-1990
1    02-01-1990
2    03-01-1990
Name: date, dtype: object
```